# Count distinct value pairs in multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, count, distinct

What query will count the number of rows, but distinct by three parameters?

Example:

```
Id      Name        Address 
==============================
1     MyName        MyAddress
2     MySecondName  Address2
```

Something like:

```
select count(distinct id,name,address) from mytable
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Since you include an id, who is probably the primary key, all counts will add up to one...

Comment: id was an example...bad example anyway

Comment: Maybe the "id" was a bad example, but the question was valid, and helped me find an answer. Have a +1

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To get a count of the number of unique combinations of `id`, `name` and `address`:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               id
             , name
             , address
        FROM   your_table
       ) As distinctified
```

Answer (score 9):

Get all distinct `id`, `name` and `address` columns and count the resulting rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY id, name, address
```

Comment: ...won't this return one row for each group? Perhaps I mis-interpreted the question...

Comment: No. `GROUP BY` simply groups multiple rows with the same value in the grouped column in a single row. So, if you have 100 rows with the same value for `name`, yes, it will return a single row, but if you have 100 rows with 10 different values for the `name` column (and you `GROUP BY name`), it will return 10 rows, each with a distinct `name`.

Comment: This is flatly false

Comment: @Dzhuneyt, I don't think this is what the op was asking.  I took it that he wanted the number of unique tuples, not counts of each unique tuple.

Answer (score 6):

Another (probably not production-ready or recommended) method I just came up with is to concat the values to a string and count this string distinctively:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT concat(id, name, address)) FROM mytable;
```

Comment: As written, this will only work id, name and address are all the same data types.   If any of these are of a different data type, you will have to use the cast() or convert() function

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id + name + address) FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Having to return the count of a unique Bill of Materials (BOM) where each BOM have multiple positions, I dd something like this:

```
select t_item, t_pono, count(distinct ltrim(rtrim(t_item)) + cast(t_pono as varchar(3))) as [BOM Pono Count]
from BOMMaster
where t_pono = 1
group by t_item, t_pono
```

Given t_pono is a smallint datatype and t_item is a varchar(16) datatype