# Merging two rows of data and getting distinct count

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

This question is in continuation to [Merging every two rows of data in a column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136683/merging-every-two-rows-of-data-in-a-column-in-sql-server)

My eventtable structure..

```
Id    UserId     EventId        EventDateTime
1       1           A           18-06-2013 10:36
2       1           B           18-06-2013 10:40
3       1           C           18-06-2013 10:46
4       1           D           18-06-2013 10:50
5       1           A           18-06-2013 13:36
```

From the earlier question I got data in the following format..

```
UserId  EventStart  EventEnd
1        A           B
1        B           C
```

Now I would like to get the count of Unique 'EventStart' and 'EventEnd' and filter them by UserId and Date/s

The Report format is

```
EventStart EventEnd Count
 A           B       5
 B           C       3
```

I know that i could use the data from the previous Question query and store it in a  table and try as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715798/count-multiple-columns-sql)

But it would be great if I could get the data straight from the 'eventtable' to the report format with the 'UserId' and 'Date' filters

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to count the occurrences, use `group by` in essentially the same query:

```
select eventstart, eventend, count(*)
from (select userId, eventid as eventstart,
             (select top 1 t2.eventid
              from mytable t2
              where t2.userid = t.userid and
                    t2.id > t.id
              order by t2.id
             ) as eventend
      from mytable t
     ) t
where eventend is not null
group by eventstart, eventend;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to filter based on userId by adding a select and groupby UserId. How do I filter based on time period i.e if a user selects a date or time period, only those eventstart, eventend and count must be shown that happened during that period.
Also, I wanted to add two more where clauses to the query with Or syntax - eventstart not in ('A', 'B') & eventstart !=eventend but I'm unable to get the OR clause working though AND clause is working- Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Arnab . . . You would just use a `where` clause to do the filtering, regardless of the column.