# count of value available in comma separated column

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a table in mysql as mentioned below :

```
create table test (
id int,
page_id varchar(2),
name varchar(255));

insert into test values 
(1,'P1','a,b,c,d,e'),
(1,'P2','f,h,z,a,c'),
(1,'P3','x,yz,g,c'),
(2,'P1','a,z'),
(2,'P2','a,c,v,b');
```

I need to count the occurrence of the values available in different pages.
For e.g.

- count of "a" is 2 **for id 1** because it is available in page P1 and
  P2.
- count of "b" is 1 **for id 1**  because it is only available in
  page P1.
- count of "c" is 3 **for id 1**  because it is only    available    in
  page P1,P2 and P3

The number of pages are approximately 2,00,000 for id 1 and 56,000 for id 2

Can anyone help me how to count the occurrence of "name" in id for the page.

Comment: how the `python` tag is related to this question? @AnkurSharma

Comment: @lemon i have the option to use the python as well to insert the aggregated data into mysql via python

Comment: Drakax this is the data :Id Page_id name
1 P1 a,b,c,d,e
1 P2 f,h,z,a,c
1 P3 x,yz,g,c
2 P1 a,z
2 P2 a,c,v,b

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion from me is fixing database design  and never store comma separated values.

One way of doing this is first you need to transform the `name` column into rows. To do so, create a number table with the maximum character length of name column.

```
create table numbers (
nr int );

insert into numbers values (1),(2), (3),(4), (5),(6);
```

Your data example:

```
create table test (
id int,
page_id varchar(2),
name varchar(255));

insert into test values 
(1,'P1','a,b,c,d,e'),
(1,'P2','f,h,z,a,c'),
(1,'P3','x,y,z,g,c'),
(2,'P1','a,z'),
(2,'P2','a,c,v,b');
```

Below query will return name column into rows

```
select id,
       page_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.name, ',', numbers.nr), ',', -1) as name
from numbers 
inner join test on CHAR_LENGTH(test.name)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(test.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.nr-1
group by id,page_id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.name, ',', numbers.nr), ',', -1)
order by id asc;
```

Finally for your expected result, apply an outer query counting:

```
select id,name,count(distinct page_id,name) as page_count
from (
       select id,
       page_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.name, ',', numbers.nr), ',', -1) as name
from numbers 
inner join test on CHAR_LENGTH(test.name)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(test.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.nr-1
group by id,page_id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.name, ',', numbers.nr), ',', -1)
     ) as t1
group by id,name
order by id asc;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5dc594b23eacc3298ca2c5a103e0fae

Note. For `count(distinct page_id,name)` both columns should have the same data types

> Refrences:
>
> [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)
>
> [Count distinct value pairs in multiple columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715798/count-distinct-value-pairs-in-multiple-columns-in-sql)

Comment: Nice fiddle! Yes, this is exactly the right approach, as Hadley describes in https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html : "Each observation must have its own row."